# Neovim throws an error running input(), runs ok in Vim

Tags: python, vim, neovim

Noob question here, Neovim throws an error when running a script using input() in the command-line window, while the same script runs in vim 8.0. eg

```
print('Enter your name:')
myName = input()
```

:! python %    <- ex command used

Nvim output:

```
myName: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 2, in <module>
    myName = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

shell returned 1
```

I prefer the way neovim runs it's scripts in it's own bottom window as opposed to vim outputting to the command line, but I have to switch to vim for any scripts using input().

Is there a nvim.init setting or a different command I can use to succeed here, or is this a known flaw in neovim? I'm on wsl using the latest vim and nvim.

Comment: The command started by `:!` is not interactive and can not accept user input, see also `:help :!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you're getting this error. But, since you are using neovim, have you tried using the built-in `terminal` emulator? The below command can be used to run the program within newovim in a new split window:

```
:vsplit term://python3 %
```

`python3` is the name of program, which can be substituted with any other program. Where `%` is the current file's path. See `:h terminal-start` for more information.

The same can be done using Vim (8.0 or above) by using the command:

```
:term python3 %
```

this will again open a new split for the program running. See `:h terminal` for more information.

A further optimization to the workflow would be to add a filetype specific mapping. In our case that would be(unix like systems) in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`

```
nnoremap <leader>r :vsplit term://python3 %<cr>
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tips, Harish. 
Both of those worked great, the term version is perfect for me for a quick run (works in nvim as well).

I notice the nvim version I have to hit 'i' to enter terminal mode in both term or vsplit term,
while in vim it automatically enters terminal mode (better).
Is there a setting I can tweak for that, or pass an option?

Also nvim exits back to the main window via enter conveniently, while in vim I have to :q back.
(minor quibbles...funny how they work slightly differently)

Both are working much better now, cheers mate. :)

Comment: In vim, there's an option to exit as soon as the job is done. `:term ++close python3 %`. See `:help term++close` for more info. And for neovim, you could use an autocommand to go into insert mode, but have to figure out what autocommand event we can use though.

Comment: Thanks but I can't use ++close, it exits before I can read the final result :)
I'll look into setting an auto-command up, cheers.

Comment: check this out: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/8816#issuecomment-410512452

Comment: Got terminal-insert working :D ...from here:
https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/8816#issuecomment-410512452


if has('nvim')
    autocmd TermOpen term://* startinsert
endif

Comment: Cool! If that solved your problem, please mark the response as the answer. I believe that's how SO works! :)