# how to resolve neovim c++ compile and run bug?

Tags: neovim

I m using neovim about few weeks and facing this problem. when I compile and execute the file the input automatically taken as "1". I don't know what is causing this problem as you can even see in the screen-shot.
I haven't given that input, it was taken by default.

Thank you :)

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Neovim throws an error running input(), runs ok in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218759/neovim-throws-an-error-running-input-runs-ok-in-vim)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/61785636/6064933 and https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/29318/15292